# Faceted qqplots with ggplot2

Tags: r, statistics, ggplot2

Say I have the following data:

```
datapoints1 = data.frame(categ=c(rep(1, n), rep(2, n)), vals1=c(rt(n, 1, 2), rnorm(n, 3, 4)))
datapoints2 = data.frame(categ=c(rep(1, n), rep(2, n)), vals2=c(rt(n, 5, 6), rnorm(n, 7, 8)))
```

Using `ggplot2`, how can I use the `facet` functionality to create in a single command two QQplots, i.e. one with the two *t* samples, the other with the two Gaussian samples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, combine both data frames:

```
dat <- cbind(datapoints1, vals2 = datapoints2[ , 2])
```

Then, sort the data:

```
dat_sort <- do.call("rbind", lapply(unique(dat$categ), FUN = function(x) {data.frame(categ = x, vals1 = sort(dat$vals1[dat$categ == x]), vals2 = sort(dat$vals2[dat$categ == x]))}))
```

It is simple if both sample vectors are of the same length:

```
ggplot() + 
 geom_point(data = dat_sort, aes(x = vals1, y = vals2)) +
 facet_wrap( ~ categ, scales = "free")
```

An example with `n = 1000`:

[image: 2 QQ plots]

Comment: I think the graph would be more usefull using `scales = "free"`

Comment: Interesting solution. I have been trying with `stat_qq` so far, to no avail.

Comment: I think there is a problem with the solution, the plots seem to get "chopped off" somehow. The problem is easier to see with two normals: `datapoints1 = data.frame(categ=c(rep(1, n), rep(2, n)), vals1=c(rnorm(n, 2, 1), rnorm(n, 5, 1)), vals2=c(rnorm(n, 2, 1), rnorm(n, 5, 1)))`. Also observe what happens when you remove the `scales = "free"` option.

Comment: No, somehow the data itself seems to get chopped off (this is what becomes apparent when you remove the `scales = "free"` option). These qqplots should look symmetric -- in the previous comment I plot a N(2,1) sample against another, and a N(5,1) sample against another, and they don't look symmetric either. Just compare the results you get to a classic `qqplot(rnorm(n, 2, 1), rnorm(n, 2, 1)` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: They look identical for the case you mention, but in the _faceted_ plot something seems to go wrong. Have you checked the example I suggest in my comment above? Try `n=1000; dat = data.frame(categ=c(rep(1, n), rep(2, n)), vals1=c(rnorm(n, 2, 1), rnorm(n, 5, 1)), vals2=c(rnorm(n, 2, 1), rnorm(n, 5, 1))); ggplot() + geom_point(data = dat, aes(x = sort(vals1), y = sort(vals2))) + facet_wrap( ~ categ)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16601/discussion-between-mitchus-and-sven-hohenstein)

Comment: There was an error in the previous version of my answer. The grouping variable in `ggplot` was not applied before the vectors were sorted. The data needs to be sorted before plotting. I updated my answer.

Comment: So you should remove the `sort` from the `ggplot` call.