# R Faceted qqplots with column and row

Tags: r

I needs to create a qqplot using facets by row and column.  I understand how to facet plot with columns and rows, but I am not sure how to set up my data.  Ultimately, I want to group my dataset by column and row, then sort the 'Modeled' results and 'Observed' results in ascending order while adding a column with the 'row' group and a column with the 'column' group.

I have been trying to modify the solution to this question, [Faceted qqplots with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369377/faceted-qqplots-with-ggplot2), , but I am not very familiar with lapply so maybe I just missed something.

Here is the code I have been working with:

```
#Dummy Data:
df <- mtcars
# Name columns as I have in my real data
df$rows <- df$cyl
df$columns <- df$gear
df$Modeled <- df$wt
df$Observed <- df$mpg

# Function to sort data while maintaining the rows & columns for use in facet later.
dat_sort <- do.call("rbind", 
                  sapply(list(unique(df$rows), unique(df$columns)), 
                         FUN = function(x) {
                           data.frame(rows = x[[1]], 
                                      columns = x[[2]], 
                                      Observed = sort(df$Observed[df$rows == x[[1]] & df$columns == x[[2]]]), 
                                      Modeled = sort(df$Modeled[df$rows == x[[1]] & df$columns == x[[2]]])
                                      )
                           }
                         ))
```

I don't get an error, but my output is definitely not what I was expecting. My output should look like this: (with correct column names)

```
rows columns Observed Modeled
6      4      17.8      2.620
6      4      19.2      2.875
6      4      21.0      3.440
6      4      21.0      3.440
4      3      21.5      2.465
8      5      15.0      3.17
8      5      15.8      3.57
```

Output from code:

```
       [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]
[1,]  6.000  6.000  6.000  6.000
[2,]  4.000  4.000  4.000  4.000
[3,] 17.800 19.200 21.000 21.000
[4,]  2.620  2.875  3.440  3.440
[5,]  4.000  4.000  4.000  4.000
[6,]  3.000  3.000  3.000  3.000
[7,] 21.500 21.500 21.500 21.500
[8,]  2.465  2.465  2.465  2.465
```

Any help would be most appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Is the expected output values correct

Comment: Ah sorry there is a typo! I will edit my question.

Comment: Do you need to just order `df1 <- df[c('rows', 'columns', 'Observed', 'Modeled')];
> df1[do.call(order, -df1),]`

Comment: I honestly haven't been able to figure out what or why its giving me the results it is giving me - so I think it is more than ordering.

Comment: Based on the code, you are `sort`ing the columns after loop over the unique values in 'row/column, and then subsetting which is made shorter with just order.  Also, the `sort` in your post is independent i.e. it breaks the row order

Comment: I don't quite understand the code you wrote (sorry still new).  Looking at the output this might be what I want, but I don't quite understand how it arrived there.  (specifically the ; >)

Comment: `>` that part is the console prompt.  Remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just need to `order` the dataset in ascending order and that can be done with `order`

```
df1 <- df[c('rows', 'columns', 'Observed', 'Modeled')]
df2 <- df1[do.call(order, -df1),]
```

---

In the OP's code, change the `sapply` to `lapply` to return as `list` (`sapply` by default uses `simplify = TRUE` to return a `matrix`)

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(list(unique(df$rows),
        unique(df$columns)), 
            FUN = function(x) {
               data.frame(rows = x[[1]], 
                          columns = x[[2]], 
                          Observed = sort(df$Observed[df$rows == x[[1]] & 
                                   df$columns == x[[2]]]), 

                          Modeled = sort(df$Modeled[df$rows == x[[1]] &
                                     df$columns == x[[2]]])
                                                               )
                                                    }
                                                  ))
#   rows columns Observed Modeled
#1    6       4     17.8   2.620
#2    6       4     19.2   2.875
#3    6       4     21.0   3.440
#4    6       4     21.0   3.440
#5    4       3     21.5   2.465
```

By doing the looping on the `unique` as a `list`, each vector is a separate `list` element and `x[[1]]`, `x[[2]]` are actually subsetting based on the 6, 4 and 4, 3 for the second element

```
list(unique(df$rows), unique(df$columns))
#[[1]]
#[1] 6 4 8

#[[2]]
#[1] 4 3 5
```

Instead, if we need to do this for corresponding elements, then use `Map` or loop over the sequence of `unique` elements (assuming they have the same length), but a more easier approach is `split`

If the lengths are same for `unique` elements, and want to subset based on corresponding values, then use `Map`

```
do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y) {
    i1 <- df$rows == x & df$columns == y
    data.frame(rows = x, columns = y,
               Observed = sort(df$Observed[i1]),
               Modeled = sort(df$Modeled[i1]))},
    unique(df$rows), unique(df$columns)))
#  rows columns Observed Modeled
#1    6       4     17.8   2.620
#2    6       4     19.2   2.875
#3    6       4     21.0   3.440
#4    6       4     21.0   3.440
#5    4       3     21.5   2.465
#6    8       5     15.0   3.170
#7    8       5     15.8   3.570
```

Comment: Thanks! The update to my original code gave me exactly what I was looking for! Do you think this would still work if my rows and columns contained strings?  Or would I need to look into your other suggestions?

Comment: @melmo I have reservations about your approach and the way it was done because you are doing `sort`ing independently which breaks the row order.  Also, as I mentioned in the post, the `list(unique(df$rows), unique(df$columns))` is a list of two vectors.  Not clear whether you need to subset based on each corresponding elements

Comment: Sorry I had to step away. Breaking the sorting is OK in this instance because I need those two columns independently sorted. Really I think I want something like unique(df$rows, df$columns).   I wanted to go with a dplyr group_by(rows, columns) approach, but then I couldn't independently sort the modeled and observed columns within that grouping.

Answer (score 1):

transpose to matrix:

```
t(dat_sort)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]  [,8]
[1,]    6    4 17.8 2.620    4    3 21.5 2.465
[2,]    6    4 19.2 2.875    4    3 21.5 2.465
[3,]    6    4 21.0 3.440    4    3 21.5 2.465
[4,]    6    4 21.0 3.440    4    3 21.5 2.465
```