# R Using map with unnamed function requiring two variables

Tags: r

I asked this question on Friday ([R Faceted qqplots with column and row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61963801/r-faceted-qqplots-with-column-and-row)) and @Akrun gave be a very useful answer that seemed to solve my issue.  However, I needed to make slight modifications to his answer so that x and y would be unique *combinations* rather than just a list of the unique values in each column, but now I cannot get this code to successfully complete.

Dummy Data:

```
df <- mtcars
# Name columns as I have in my real data
df$rows <- df$cyl
df$columns <- df$gear
df$Modeled <- df$wt
df$Observed <- df$mpg
```

Code1:

```
  dat_sort <- do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y) {
    i1 <- df$rows == x & df$columns == y
    print(nrow(df$Observed[i1]))
    print(nrow(df$Modeled[i1]))
    data.frame(rows = x, columns =y,
               Observed = sort(df$Observed[i1]),
               Modeled = sort(df$Modeled[i1]))},
    unique(df$rows[c("rows", "columns")]), unique(df$columns[c("rows", "columns")])))
```

The error:

```
Error in data.frame(rows = rep(x, sum(i1 == TRUE)), columns = rep(y, sum(i1 ==  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 6888, 455, 574
Called from: data.frame(rows = rep(x, sum(i1 == TRUE)), columns = rep(y, sum(i1 == 
    TRUE)), Observed = sort(df$Observed[i1 == TRUE]), Modeled = sort(df$Modeled[i1 == 
    TRUE]))
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had a couple of issues.  I am posting my answer in case someone runs across a similar problem.

The largest issue, was that map() needs the VECTORS to walk through.  In my code, I left it as a data.frame.  This was resolved by use of the [[column#]] in my code below.

My real dataset has NA values in the Observed data, but the sort function by default excludes NAs.

```
  ## Sort data by unique combination of rows and columns
  dat_sort <- do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y) {
    i1 <- df$rows == x & df$columns == y
    data.frame(rows = x, 
               columns = y,
               Observed = sort(df$Observed[i1], decreasing = FALSE, na.last = FALSE),
               Modeled = sort(df$Modeled[i1], decreasing = FALSE, na.last = FALSE)
               )},
    unique(df[,c("rows", "columns")])[[1]], unique(df[,c("rows", "columns")])[[2]]))
```